# Trying to figure out how to use recursion c#

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm learning about recursion and I want to create a function to type something and give me the same string but inverse but can't find the logic for it.

```
    public static string Reverse(string text, int textlength)
    {
        if (textlength== 0)
        {
            return text.ElementAt(textlength).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return Reverse(text, textlength - 1);
        }           
    }
```

How could I do that using recursion?

Comment: What do you expect `text.ElementAt(-1)` to return?

Comment: is suppose that should return the first character, supposing that the word is "letter" it should return "l" as last iteration

Comment: @JavierSalas sooooo does it work this way?

Comment: I can't see how this relates to recursion.  How many times do you want to reverse the whole string?

Comment: Are you right @zzxyz, I changed now that.

Comment: @Khyron just want to reverse the string for example if I write "Letter" the output should be "retteL"

Comment: @Javier Salas Your code implies that you're shortening the string, but there's nothing in the wording of your question about that.  I think you might not understand what you're trying to do yet, which is understandable when you're first learning recursion.  If you recursively reverse "Letter", it will never end.  If you shorten the string, there will eventually be a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is always about two cases, the base case and the recursive case.

The base case is when the string is 0 or 1 characters - the reverse is just what was passed in, so we return `text`.

The recursive case is when `text` is longer than 1 character, we must define the operation in terms of itself. In this case, the reverse of the string is the reverse of the rest of the string followed by the first character.

```
public static string Reverse(string text) {
    if (text.Length <= 1) // base case
        return text;
    else // recursive case
        return Reverse(text.Substring(1))+text.Substring(0, 1);
}
```